# Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar in Gingerbread(sdk 9)

Tags: android

I use material in my application , it works right with (minSdkVersion 11+) but with minSdkVersion 9 the application crashes

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/splash">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Error is:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

ToolBarStyle is:

```
<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="">
  <item name= "popupTheme"> @style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light </item>
  <item name="theme"> @style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Comment: have you added v7 support library

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0' 
@Nilesh

Comment: @Nilesh the app works well, but on devices (sdk 9) does not work

Comment: Post your ToolBarStyle

Comment: 1) minHeight=0dp on a toolbar is nonsense. Use ?actionBarSize. 2) Does your theme extend one of Theme.AppCompat themes? It needs to be so to resolve ?actionBarSize and ?colorPrimary. 3) Post @style/ToolBarStyle definition.

Comment: <style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="">
        <item name= "popupTheme"> @style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light  </item>
        <item name="theme"> @style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
    </style>